# CKEditor filebrowserUploadUrl Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

File uploaded successfully and server send response

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, 'http://example.com/1504678435.jpg', '');
</script>
```

But after success, I found an error in my browser console

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Looking for help if anybody knows about it.

Comment: Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.